# The phrase to express "how much time a user spends on a web page"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, expressions

Say a user spent 10 mins on a webpage.

Can I say that this user's "**residence time**" on this webpage is 10 mins?
Or is there any other better phrase to express this?

Comment: Would this be better on the UI page?  I’m pretty sure they have a term for this.

Comment: The ***residence time*** is the average time that a unit of feed stays in a vessel or stage during a continuous process.  So its better to used

Comment: As @Jim noted: Better on [ux.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [site](https://edit.co.uk/blog/understanding-google-analytics-time-page-session-duration/) suggests the expressions “time on page” and “session duration”:

> In many Google Analytics reports, you’ll see metrics called ‘***Time on Page’ or ‘Session Duration***’. If you’re asking “What does that mean”, with any metric you can hover over the “?” beside the metric name to understand what it is.
>
> ***Time on Page:*** The average amount of time a user spends on the page on your website.

￼

> What about Time on Site? Time on Site isn’t actually called that any more – it’s called ‘***Session Duration’.*** Going forward, I’ll refer to it as Session Duration, although these names are interchangeable.
>   Session Duration: How long a user spent on your site in total.

(edit.co.uk)

Answer (score 1):

When a human visits a website, they "engage" with it- user engagement, [level of]. While not a measure of time, for human visitors, it may be viewed as "quality time" spent on a website as opposed to robot visitors and page loads.

Comment: Are there any other types of users apart from humans? A visitor is a visitor, a user is a user. Never heard someone being called a human user on a website.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as ***Dwell Time***

Described on this [WordStream blog](https://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2014/06/10/dwell-time) as:

> Simply put, dwell time is the actual length of time that a visitor spends on a page before returning to the SERPs<sup>1</sup>

1<sub>*SERP*: Search engine results page</sub>